# Get one record by having the id of two others

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB and I have a simple schema :

```
User -> (AccessWith) -> AccessToken -> (HasClient) -> Client
```

(name) are edges an others are vertices.

#### I have the User and Client RID and I want to get the corresponding AccessToken, how can I do that ?

I'm currently doing this :

```
select expand($token) 
   from #1:1 
   let $token = out('AccessWith') 
   where $token.out('HasClient').@rid = #2:1
```

(**#1:1** is the User RID and **#2:1** the Client RID)

But this request doesn't work. The where clause has no effect at all. I can remove it or put a non-existent RID, I always have all the AccessToken of the #1:1 user as a result.

So I would like to understand exactly how to use the out() (or in) function in the where clause and succeed to filter on the User RID (it works fine) **and** the Client RID at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select from (
  select expand( out('AccessWith') ) from #1:1 
) where #2:1 in out('HasClient').@rid
```

The inner query returns all the AccessToken instances from the user, then you execute a filtering against that result set. It's there that WHERE should be applied. Select and Traverse can be pipelined one inside another one.

You could also do this:

```
select from AccessToken where #1:1 in in() and #2:1 in out()
```

But Starting from a node is usually faster.

Comment: Thanks @Lvca, unfortunately your first request still doesn't work (no AccessToken is recovered). But I have been able to make it works by replacing the where clause with this : **where #2:1 contains out('HasClient')**
Can you tell why I need to use the contains keyword to make it works ?

Comment: I've changed my response, because you're right: the returning of out() is a collection, so you should use IN/CONTAINS.